# Controlling quicktime movie from javascript does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, embed, quicktime

I've got a problem controlling a quicktime movie from javascript. I am embedding a video in my HTML page using `<video>` HTML5 element - with fallback to quicktime if the browser doesn't support it (e.g. IE 8) (I have a specific requirement of "no flash", but quicktime is allowed).  The video is displayed in a popup; when the popup is being closed, I want to stop video playback.  I can do this successfully in HTML5, but the quicktime control is not working.

My html looks like this:

```
<video width="360" height="298" autobuffer="autobuffer" controls="controls" id="video" tabindex="0">
    <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="/data/mmg-demo.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg" src="/data/mmg-demo.ogv"></source>
    <object width="360" height="298" id="videoem" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" classid="clsid:02bf25d5-8c17-4b23-bc80-d3488abddc6b">
        <param value="/data/mmg-demo.mp4" name="src">
        <param value="false" name="autoplay">
        <param value="true" name="controller">
        <embed width="360" height="298" name="videoem" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" loop="false" controller="true" autoplay="false" src="../files/380/380523/video.mp4">
    </object>
</video>
```

The pop-up close javascript function looks like this:

```
function closePopup {
    //stop html5 playback if it's there
    if(typeof document.getElementById('video').pause == 'function') {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
    }
    //stop playback of quicktime embed if it's there
    if(document.getElementById('videoem')) {
        document.getElementById('videoem').SetRate(0.0);
    }
    $('#demo-video').fadeOut();
}
```

I've tested this exact same quicktime code in firefox - and it works fine.  Moreover, examples in other forums that claim to work, do not work in IE 8 (e.g. see http://lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-api/2008/Mar/msg00187.html - does not work in IE 8).

Line `document.getElementById('videoem').SetRate(0.0)` causes `Object does not support this property or method` error.

I'm not sure where else to look.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out.  The trick is to use the ID from the `<embed>` element and not the `<object>` element.  So the final (working) code I got is this.

HTML:

```
<div id="mkt-video" style="position:fixed;width:360px;background-color:black;padding:10px;border:solid 2px white;display:none;z-index:100003">
    <video id="video" width="360" height="298" controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer">
        <source src="/data/mmg-demo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
        <source src="/data/mmg-demo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <object classid='clsid:02bf25d5-8c17-4b23-bc80-d3488abddc6b' width="360" height="298" codebase='http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab' id="videoem-object">
            <param name='src' value="/data/mmg-demo.mp4" />
            <param name='autoplay' value="false" />
            <param name='controller' value="true" />
            <param name="enablejavascript" value="true" />
            <embed src="../files/380/380523/video.mp4" width="360" height="298" autoplay="false" controller="true" loop="false" pluginspage='http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/' name="videoem" id="videoem"></embed>
        </object>
    </video>
</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
function closeVideo() {
    if(typeof document.getElementById('video').pause == 'function') {
        document.getElementById('video').pause();
    }
    try {
        document.getElementById('videoem-object').SetRate(0.0);
    }
    catch (err) {}
    $('#mkt-video').fadeOut();
}
```

The "try-catch" is required, because IE9 still creates the embed object but of some strange type and throws errors of some strange content.  Anyway, it works fine now.