# Embedding Adobe Flash Animation With Image Fallback Internet Explorer 10 Windows 7

Tags: flash, windows-7, internet-explorer-10

I have little flash animation on the home page of a site I made. I want it to fall back gracefully to a static image if the user doesn't have flash. This has been working just fine.

Then I got the Internet Explorer 10 update for Windows 7. Now I get nothing, not even the image fallback. If, in the Developer Tools, I change the document mode to IE 9 standards, it works just fine. But "Standards (Page Default)" standards, which I guess means IE 10 standards, shows nothing. All other browsers behave, except IE10... Why?

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="300" height="236"
    id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="MyMovie.swf" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="MyMovie.swf" width="300" height="236">
        <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf" />
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <img src="Images/MyPlaceholder.jpg" alt="This is a placeholder" />
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: Right now my workaround is to add a meta tag to the header and force IE9... Any better ideas? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling quicktime movie from javascript does not work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836822/controlling-quicktime-movie-from-javascript-does-not-work-in-ie)